# Magento 2.2.2 error .htaccess IfVersion 2.4

Tags: .htaccess, magento

In the default .htaccess in Magento 2.2.2 there are in 2 of the things like below:

```
<Files cron.php>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

There are someting about 20 of these for some files (eg. composer.json, composer.lock, .gitignore, etc)

When updating magento i gave a lot of errors, when i remove them out of the htaccess the problem was gone.

Wij are this versionchecks there, wat do the do and what can happen when i remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem on Centos(Cpanel) Apache 2.4. The issue was resolved by enabling the `mod_version` module for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of Magento do not have support for Apache version >=2.4. I used to replace `order allow,deny`                                                                          and `deny from all` lines with `Require all denied` in htaccess files manually to resolve the issue.

From the Magento 2.2.2 version, code is changed to support apache version >= 2.4 also. ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11459/files )

As per the info you have mentioned, I inferred that your Apache version is < 2.4 , rather than editing all 24 files, you can `load mod_version`.

You have to load version moudle from apache configuration file as below.

**LoadModule version_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_version.so**

otherwise you may get "Internal server error".

Answer (score 0):

This is apache versioning.
You can get more details from the above GitHub link
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10810

These changes are made as per security prospect to improve the direct file access algorithm.